# how do i validate input when using scanner?

Tags: java

When ever i input an integer for the high number it works and the validation works when i input a character as it brings up the error message.

however, i cant get it to do the same thing for the low number?

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

here is the full code

```
package client;
import static com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.FeatureState.is;
import static com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.PropertyState.is;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

  public static int Highnumber;   
  public static int Lownumber;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String hostName = "localhost"; 
        int hostPort = 4444; 
        if (args.length != 0) {
            if (args[0] != null) {
                hostName = args[0]; 
            }
            if (args[1] != null) {
                hostPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to Connect to Server");

        try (Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostName, hostPort);
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream()));
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()))) {
            Scanner ScannerInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.println("Enter High Number -");
        Integer highnumber = null;
        while (highnumber == null) {
            try {
                highnumber = Integer.parseInt(ScannerInput.next());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, ENTER AN INTEGER:");
            }
        }
        Integer lownumber = null;
        System.out.println("Enter low Number -");
        while (lownumber == null) {
            try {
                Integer number = Integer.parseInt(ScannerInput.next());
                if (number <= highnumber) {
                    lownumber = number;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR,needs to be lower");
                 }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, ENTER AN INTEGER:");
            }
        }

        Highnumber=highnumber;
        Lownumber=lownumber ;
```

getting erros in the following section:

```
    }
           int numberToFind = Integer.parseInt(is.readLine());           
            System.out.println("Target Number Set"  +  "\nStart Guessing!:");
            int Tries = 0; 
            int UserInput = 0;
        while (UserInput != numberToFind) {        
           UserInput = ScannerInput.nextInt();           
           os.writeInt(UserInput);
           os.flush();
           System.out.println(is.readLine()); 
           Tries++;            
       }
        System.out.println("Well Done! You found the number " + numberToFind + " in " + Tries  + " tries");  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception:  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: your are doing ScannerInput.nextInt();  before the assignment is that on purpose ?

Comment: also you have a second while after the while loop ?  which probably even throws a compiler error `} while (Lownumber >= Highnumber);`

Comment: ok i took out the while loop but when i run and enter integer for the low number it just keeps letting me put any integer or character in and doesnt end?

Comment: did you also remove the ScannerInput.nextInt();  thats not assigned ?

Comment: for example line 4 in the first and line 5 in the second ?

Comment: yeah removed both but still having same problem. also when i type in an integer for when inputting the low number the error message comes up? i want this to come up when anything but an integer is inputted :/

Comment: you are returning the same text in both cases

Comment: any ideas how i can go about fixing that?

Comment: change the message in one of the System.out.print() ?

Comment: the lowest  System.out.print("ERROR, ENTER AN INTEGER:"); should probably say number too high or similar

Comment: ok just stuck on how to validate it then now? i want the error message to come up when a character is typed instead or integer

Comment: I think you need to wrap the lower loop in another loop thats checking for the size

Answer (score 0):

ok ive done a little restructureing to not have to layer while loops

```
        //Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter High Number -");
        Integer highnumber = null;
        while (highnumber == null) {
            try {
                highnumber = Integer.parseInt(clientInput.next());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, ENTER AN INTEGER:");
            }
        }
        Integer lownumber = null;
        System.out.println("Enter low Number -");
        while (lownumber == null) {
            try {
                Integer number = Integer.parseInt(clientInput.next());
                if (number <= highnumber) {
                    lownumber = number;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR,needs to be lower");
                 }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR, ENTER AN INTEGER:");
            }
        }

        Highnumber=highnumber;
        Lownumber=lownumber ;

    }
```

Comment: ive edited my question to show the full code if this helps.

Comment: well this example should work for your example (except i renamed the variables to start with lowercase which I think is the standard)

Comment: if the numbers can be assigned before hand use temporary variables for the numbers until the printlns at the end and assign them to the static values at that point

Comment: done this now.. new problem tho.. when input the lower number in nothing happens. just lets me keep adding integers

Comment: oO It doesnt do that in my example ?

Comment: fixed the userInput

Comment: did I break something ? I just added the print ? no it seems to work for me mybe thers an error in the rest of your code ? do you have a stacktrace ?

Comment: if you have a stacktrace its usually best to go to the first point in the stacktrace thats in your own code and debug there to check wether the values are what they are supposed to be

Comment: ok i will look into this. i have edited my original question to show my full code now if that helps any. thanks :)

Comment: how about writing it in the same structure as the lower number example except you compare if the number equals what it should be

Answer (score -1):

According to your requirement,i developed sample code with comment you will understand logic behind program.

```
int higer_number = 0;
int lower_number;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        /**
         * putting this section into try catch,because if you get characters or some
         * other input this will throw exception.
         */
    try {
            /**
             * Entering high number as input
             */
System.out.print("Enter High Number :");
higer_number = scan.nextInt();
            /**
             * Entering low number as input
             */
System.out.print("Enter Lower Number :");
lower_number = scan.nextInt();
            /**
             * Checking is low value is lower then high value?
             */
if (lower_number >= higer_number) {
    System.out.println("PLease Enter Low Value Then Higer Number.");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Integer");
}

        scan.close();
```